# Using "past" values to define current values in GEKKO equation

Tags: gekko

I am writing the GEKKO equations to determine a vehicle's gear box ratio which depends on the vehicle's previous derivatives. Is there a way to set a variable to the time shifted value of another variable?

Ex:

v=0,[1,2,3,4,5]

shifted_v=[0,1,2,3,4]

where the square bracket is the horizon and v is a state variable defined by equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to shift data sets is to use the **numpy.roll** function.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,5,6)
y = np.roll(x,-1) # shift left
y[-1] = 6
z = np.roll(x,1)  # shift right
z[0] = -1
print('x: ' + str(x))
print('y: ' + str(y))
print('z: ' + str(z))
```

You can apply this strategy using Gekko variables by using the .value property such as:

```
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
m.time = np.linspace(0,5,6)
x = m.Param(value=m.time)
y = m.Param()
y.value = np.roll(x.value,-1)
y.value[-1] = 6
z = m.Param()
z.value = np.roll(x.value,1)
z.value[0] = -1
```

There is also a [TIME_SHIFT feature in Gekko](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmTimeShift) that automatically shifts values as if they were advancing in time. The **TIME_SHIFT** option controls how much the values are shifted with every solve. The time shift happens at the beginning of the solve. Here is a more complete example with a visualization of the result.

[image: Time shift with Gekko]

```
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
m = GEKKO()
m.time = np.linspace(0,5,6)
x = m.Param(value=m.time)
y = m.Param()
y.value = np.roll(x.value,-1)
y.value[-1] = 6
z = m.Param()
z.value = np.roll(x.value,1)
z.value[0] = -1
s = m.Var()
m.Equation(s==x+y-z)
m.options.IMODE=4
m.solve()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,x.value,label='x')
plt.plot(m.time,y.value,label='y')
plt.plot(m.time,z.value,label='z')
plt.legend()
# solve a second time
m.options.TIME_SHIFT = 1 # default is 1
m.solve()
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,x.value,label='x')
plt.plot(m.time,y.value,label='y')
plt.plot(m.time,z.value,label='z')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

From your question, it appears that you need to calculate the previous derivative of a variable. If you need to time shift a value during the calculation, not just in the initialization phase, then I would recommend a [discrete state space model](https://www.apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/DiscreteStateSpace) with a delay of 1 time step. The link provides an example of how to implement this with 4 steps of delay. You would want to modify the discrete state space matrices to have 1 step of delay between the derivative and gear-box ratio.